# How can I use expected_conditions.text_to_be_present_in_element_value, but with the _text parameter being any String from a tuple?

Tags: python, selenium, webdriverwait

I use the following code to wait one minute, or until the `_text` parameter of `EC.text_to_be_present_in_element_value` is equal to the String `to_inp`:

```
# Python
to_inp = "secret"
WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.text_to_be_present_in_element_value((By.ID, "user_guess"), to_inp))

<!-- HTML -->
<input type="text" class="form-control text-center" id="user_guess">
```

That works great, but for the practical use I need it to check if the String is within a tuple, as such:

```
# Python
to_inp = ('ananas', 'banana', 'mango') # text in input has to be equal to any of those
WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.text_to_be_present_in_element_value((By.ID, "user_guess"), to_inp))

<!-- HTML -->
<input type="text" class="form-control text-center" id="user_guess">
```

And I get the following error:

```
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not tuple
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your own implementation based on `text_to_be_present_in_element_value` from `expected_conditions`

```
class TextToBePresentInElementValue:

    def __init__(self, locator, texts):
        self.locator = locator
        self.texts = texts

    def __call__(self, driver):
        try:
            element_text = driver.find_element(*self.locator).get_attribute("value")
            return element_text in self.texts
        except StaleElementReferenceException:
            return False

to_inp = ('ananas', 'banana', 'mango')
WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(TextToBePresentInElementValue((By.ID, "user_guess"), to_inp))
```

Comment: I tried this solution, while it doesn't show any error it seems that element_text is always empty even when I manually enter text in the input.

Comment: @PaulLemarchand Sorry, missed the fact that you are looking for `value`, see updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is `presence_of_all_elements_located` in selenium you can think of.

```
to_inp = ('ananas', 'banana', 'mango')
new_list = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.ID, "user_guess")))
sorted(to_inp, key=lambda x: x[1])
new_list.sort()
b = list(set(to_inp).intersection(set(new_list)))
print(b)
```

Comment: This would return `new_list` if something else is typed in the input though, wouldn't it?